# Animating Label and display data on xcode 4.2

Tags: objective-c, ios5, storyboard

im a newbie on making ios app.

I have some problems on using label and data now.
I want to put a label (text) in my home screen and when people push it, some data (text, picture or something else) will appear under that label. And when people push it again, the data will disappear.

I have searched on google but sorry i havent got it.

If u guys dont have time to explain it clearly for me, just give me books that cover these problems (which page or chapter) i will find on it.

Thank u very much, have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `UITapGesture` to the `UILable` & handle the tap events.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[myLabel addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
myLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[tapGestureRecognizer release];

-(void)handleTapGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{
    //do whatever you want.
}
```

If you want to set only the text then use `UILable` else use custom `UIButton`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a label for this, Use a UIButton and change the shape to custom. Then it'll look like a label without the button shape. do whatever you want inside button press event

Comment: Thx. I got it but How about the effect? I want the data look like it will release gradually down to the bottom of the screen and vise versa. Please give me advices.